# "Named" as a past participle adjective or relative clause

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

- 'I passed the exam.' The exam = 'The passed exam.'
- 'I named the boy.' The boy = 'The named boy.'
- 'I called the girl.' The girl = 'The called girl.'
- What = 'The boy named John.'?
- What = 'The girl called Sarah.'?

Is 'named' and 'called' past participles as adjectives? Are they relative clauses with ellipsis of 'who is'? Or is it something else?

This has bugged me for weeks now. Please help.

For a bonus, what = 'A streetcar named desire."?

Comment: Stack Exchange formatting is somewhat quirky. To get paragraphs to line-break properly, insert a blank line between paragraphs. Alternatively, if you put two spaces at the end of a line, that also signifies the end of a paragraph.

Comment: 1. Try to find the answer and let us know. 2. See also [ell.se]